# Codded-UI Mouse.Click Throw an Argument Exception

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, coded-ui-tests

I am working on Visual Studio Environment with Selenium and CodedUI together.
while i am trying to build a Unit Test with those Infrastructures i am getting an exception that i could not handle.

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll but was not handled in
>   user code
>
> Additional information: Invalid value for parameter. Value: -1.
>   Parameter: SearchTimeout.

here is part of the source code that i am running:

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.Disabled;
BossHome.FindScreen.UserNameField = username;
BossHome.FindScreen.Serch();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
BossHome.RelatedAccounts.closeRelatedAccountWindow();
BossHome.AccountsTab.MoveToManualDepositWindow();
Thread.Sleep(10000);                       
Mouse.Click(this.UIMap.UIItem702553427MultiInWindow.UIItem702553427MultiInDocument10.UIGrantBonusMainIframeFrame1.UIHttpsbossmiragebackoDocument.UIMy_frameFrame.UIItem888comCashierDocument.UIItem100Pane);
            Mouse.Click(this.UIMap.UIItem702553427MultiInWindow.UIItem702553427MultiInDocument10.UIGrantBonusMainIframeFrame1.UIHttpsbossmiragebackoDocument.UIMy_frameFrame.UIItem888comCashierDocument.UIEntercardnumberEdit);
            Keyboard.SendKeys(this.UIMap.UIItem702553427MultiInWindow.UIItem702553427MultiInDocument10.UIGrantBonusMainIframeFrame1.UIHttpsbossmiragebackoDocument.UIMy_frameFrame.UIItem888comCashierDocument.UIEntercardnumberEdit, "nadavb");
```

Thanks,
nadav

Comment: Why do you use WaitForReadyLevel.Disabled? If the control isn't loaded and available when you Mouse.Click, the search won't find anything and may time out. I see you use a thread.Sleep to work around this, but this isn't robust. I'd suggest using the default WaitForReadyLevel (UiThreadOnly I believe).

Comment: thx, your answer helped me!